# Is there a way to redirect the Joomla! Administrator login?

Tags: administrator, login, redirect

When I login on the front end I have the ability to choose where that login goes to.

On the backend is there a way to choose this?  Currently it goes to the dashboard but I'd prefer to make it go to a component as that's the main use of the site.

If not, can anyone give me a clue how to achieve this via the Administration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not want to give any custom solution here since it looks like that this feature is already given by a third party plugin.

You should try this plugin: https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/system-redirect-on-backend-login/

**According to the few lines of documentation** of the plugin it does exactly what you need. Even more, since you can set specific user group to be redirected to a component (set by you) after admin login. I did not try that but it looks like it is a newer plugin, actually 5 months old at the moment. And I just downloaded it to looking into it - it is free - and it is a nice, simple system plugin with actually 15 lines of code which checks the **user** and the **usergroup** and if the user group is set by you to redirect then it calls the Router to redirect to the given component.

**The plugin code could be a bit improved**, cleaned here and there, as I see it was made in a hurry by a PHP programmer who has about a strong medium level understanding of Joomla back-end programming (which is a good level considering the complexity of Joomla today). It is quite useful and looks like a working code base for this admin redirect. Nice and neat solution for this simple job. You can later improve this plugin for yourself a bit if you would like to...

Comment: Amazing, thanks for commenting on the code quality, that's really helpful.